# What is the actual structure of ECS Service ARNs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to grant the ecs:UpdateService permission in an IAM policy like below:

```
{
            "Sid": "AllowECS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "ecs:UpdateService"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:service/my-service"
        }
```

where the service ARN is as listed by the cli `aws ecs list-services` (and `describe-services`).

However the UpdateService API call fails with an AccessDenied error saying the process does not have permission to the service with ARN:

`arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:service/*my-cluster*/my-service`

I cannot find any reference to the ARN for an ECS service *including the the cluster name*, and the documentation for the cli "ecs describe-services" explicitly says:

> *serviceArn -> (string)*
>   The ARN that identifies the service. The ARN
>   contains the arn:aws:ecs namespace, followed by the Region of the
>   service, the AWS account ID of the service owner, the service
>   namespace, and then the service name. For example,
>   arn:aws:ecs:region:012345678910:service/my-service .

If I change the IAM policy to actually use the ARN shown in the error, which *includes the cluster name*, then the UpdateService completes successfully.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, should an ECS service ARN include the cluster name? If so, how can I obtain that version of the ARN as the AWS APIs all seem to return the version that doesn't include the cluster name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue lately as well.

Basically, there is a new ECS ARN as mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2/). It's still under opt-in period till end of this year.

Please find below the old and new format comparison.

[image: Comparison old and new ARN]

From your question, I think that your AWS account is also opted in for new format.

More details can be found [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/faqs/#Transition_to_new_ARN_and_ID_format)